# Django access related property dynamically?

Tags: python, django, getattr

I am using getattr to access properties of a model dynamically like so (Assuming the Student model has a property called name):

```
students = Student.objects.all()
property = 'name'


for student in students:
    print getattr(student, property)
```

This works fine, however I'm wondering if it is possible to access a property of a related record in the same way, for example (Assuming each Student has a related Group with a property called title):

```
students = Student.objects.selected_related()
property = 'group.title'


for student in students:
    print getattr(student, property)
```

With this, I just get the error 'Student has no attribute group.title'

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to check if the object in question has the property you're looking for with `hasattr` or handle the potential exception when you try to access an attribute that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the following code will do what you asked:

```
students = Student.objects.all()
attr_chain = "group.title".split(".")

for student in students:
    item = student
    for attr in attr_chain:
        item = getattr(item, attr)

    print "%s is in the group %s" % (student, item)
```

Depending on your needs **I would suggest that you look into Django's `values_list` function** on the Queryset class, it can shorten and simplify code in many cases.

```
name_attr = "name"

#If you look in the documentation you will see why I use "__" here
group_title_attr = "group__title" 

for student_name, group_title in Student.objects.all().values_list(name_attr, group_title_attr):
    print "%s is in the group %s" % (student_name, group_title)
```

The relevant docs are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

Comment: Thanks.  All good answers.  This one was particularly useful for what I was working on though.

Answer (score 3):

looks like you are looking for

```
getattr(getattr(student, property), subproperty)
```

you may be able to do with by looping over `property.split('.')`

Answer (score 2):

you can always use `from functools import reduce`

and procced like this:

```
reduce(getattr, "some.nested.property".split("."), student)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless every object in select_related has a property called 'title', that's going to blow up. What does select_related bring back for a Student model? I'm guessing it's more than just a Group object. You'd need to wrap this in a try/ except block or test the object to see if it is of the same type as Group (e.g., isinstance(x, Group)).

What are you actually trying to achieve? This seems a little tortured. Also, I would suggest a re-labelling to make things clearer:

```
for obj in student_related:
    # print type(obj)
    print getattr(obj, property)
```

You're not actually getting Student objects in that list.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? Not sure what's wrong here.